# Android: pixel-perfect layouts for each resolution

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, adt

I want to create an app with pixel-perfect graphics for each resolution (I'm going to support only 3 or 4 of them). In my main activity I created new layout and selected 800x600 from available qualifiers. I edited it and then I created folder "layout-1280x720" for another resolution. I copied activity_main.xml from "layout-800x600" to "layout-1280x720" and edited new copy. But now when I run it in android emulator at 1280x720 I see layout from 800x600.
How can I create different layouts for each exact resolution?

Comment: "I'm going to support only 3 or 4 of them" -- that's not possible, unless you are not planning on distributing the app. "I created folder "layout-1280x720"" -- those resolution-dependent resource sets have been deprecated for nearly three years, and I don't know if they even work anymore. "How can I create different layouts for each exact resolution?" -- you don't, any more than you create Web pages for exact browser window sizes, ignoring the fact that the user is perfectly capable of resizing those windows.

Comment: "pixel perfect" works nowhere really...

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this URI

http://android4beginners.com/2013/07/appendix-c-everything-about-sizes-and-dimensions-in-android/

You can see there a proper approach for your issue.

Comment: Instead of adding just link as answer, could you please explain the relative part? Links are not always reliable and may not work in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually close to impossible to do that, because android doesn't have percent dimensions, of course you can use weight coefficients, but it won't be the solution. I will recommend you to use this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nazacheres.com.pixelperfect), which overlays your template over everything. It makes layout creating much easier and faster.